# Neo4j add huge number of relationships to already existing nodes

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, relationships, large-data

I have labels Person and Company with millions of nodes.
I am trying to create a relationship: 
 `(person)-[:WORKS_AT]->(company)` based on a unique company number property that exists in both labels.
I am trying to do that with the following query:
`MATCH (company:Company), (person:Person)
WHERE company.companyNumber=person.comp_number 
CREATE (person)-[:WORKS_AT]->(company)`
but the query takes too long to execute and eventually fails.
I have indexes on `companyNumber` and `comp_number`.
So, my question is: it there a way to create the relationships by segments, for example (50000, then another 50000 etc...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a temporary label to mark things as completed, and add a limit step before creating the relationship. When you are all done, just remove the label from everyone.

```
MATCH (company:Company)
WITH company
MATCH (p:Person {comp_number: company.companyNumber} )
WHERE NOT p:Processed
WITH company, p
LIMIT 50000
MERGE (p) - [:WORKS_AT] -> (company)
SET p:Processed
RETURN COUNT(*) AS processed
```

That will return the number (usually 50000) of rows that were processed; when it returns less than 50000 (or whatever you set the limit to), you are all done. Run this guy then:

```
MATCH (n:Processed)
WITH n LIMIT 50000
REMOVE n:Processed
RETURN COUNT(*) AS processed
```

until you get a result less than 50000. You can probably turn all of these numbers up to 100000 or maybe more, depending on your db setup.

Comment: Note that there is an APOC Procedure [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) that can help batch it up so it doesn't have to be done manually. I'm not submitting this as an actual answer right now due to some potential bugs I encountered when trying it myself when using a :Processed label as in Tore's solution. If they fix it I'll submit it as a viable solution.